# WebdriverIO: How to write a if else if statement javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, jasmine, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I need to switch between different urls depending on what the first part of the url says.

EX:
https://prod.com/ and then i need to add form/address/type/etc?stuff
or
https://test.com/ and then i need to add a different form/address/type/etc?stuff

I did something like this

```js
const Page = require("./page");

class OpeningClass extends Page {
  open() {
    if (this.url === "https://qa_environment.com/") {
      this.openForm2QA();
    } else if (this.url === "https://testing_environment.com/") {
      this.openForm2DEV();
    } else {
      this.openForm2PROD();
    }
  }

  openForm2QA() {
    return super.open("stuff/address?stuff&junk");
  }

  openForm2DEV() {
    return super.open("graphs/address?apples&bananas");
  }

  openForm2PROD() {
    return super.open("history/address?westside&bestside");
  }
}
```

So far the qa and prod one works but not the else if one in the middle.
Using WDIO and jasmine in Javscript

Comment: Depending on the input you're expecting, [`string.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) or [`string.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I used else if (this.url.to.include "testing_environment") {